# Python replace None with blank with tuple data set by keeping the field name linkage

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Currently have below data set which is row Iterator and values are in tuple. I'm trying to formulate code to replace None with blank and access the tuple value based on field name. Any thought how I can do

current data set:

```
print(data)
Row(('Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
Row(('James', 'Burns', 34, 'M', 'CA'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
Row(('Matt', 'Dan', 45, None, 'NY'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
```

Approach I took to replace None was convert tuple to list perform replace and convert back to tuple. but during that case, field name linkage got lost. How to replace without droping field name linkage as I want to utilize row.fname and row.lname call in downstream process

```
for row in data:
    a = list(row)
    c = ['' if x is None else x for x in a]
    d = tuple(c)

print(d.fname)
print(d.age)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about the `Row()` type...

Comment: Source data is extract from bigquery using query()  (https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.html).

Comment: below three 

print(row) 
Row(('Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})

print(list(row))
['Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX']

print(row.values())
('Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX')

Comment: You can probably use something like this `list(Row(('a', 'b'), {'x': 0, 'y': 1}).items())`resulting in 
`[('x', 'a'), ('y', 'b')]` which would give in your case `[('fname', 'Robert'), ('lname', 'Hoit'), ....]`  making it easy to access or change this with `val = lamda item_list, dict, field_name = item_list[dict[field_name]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm assuming that `data` is a tuple that contains tuples and dictionaries. If so, then:

```
def rem_none(row):
    if type(row) != dict:
        row = list(row)
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] is None:
                row[i] = ''
        row = tuple(row)
        return row
    return row


for row in data:
    print(rem_none(row))
```

Comment: Since data is rowIterator object calling rem_none() function with in the rowiterator loop error on below line
`temp = list(tup[n])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable `

`for row in data:
     rem_none(row)`

Comment: @Qzia88 What exactly is the type of ```row```?

Comment: type for `print(type(row))` is 
`<class 'google.cloud.bigquery.table.Row'>`

Comment: if i prints each row within the for loop its `Row (('Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})`

Comment: @Qzia88 Tell me what does the final command print out: ```for row in data:```, ```row=list(row)```, ```print(row[0], row[1])```

Comment: It print 
`Robert Hoit`

Comment: @Qzia88 okay I edited the answer, try now?

Comment: Thanks, this worked and able to achieve values with none replace with blank